# Creating and returning Observable from Angular 2 Service

Tags: angular, observable

This is more of a "best practices" question. There are three players: a `Component`, a `Service` and a `Model`. The `Component` is calling the `Service` to get data from a database. The `Service` is using:

```js
this.people = http.get('api/people.json').map(res => res.json());
```

to return an `Observable`.

The `Component` could just subscribe to the `Observable`:

```js
    peopleService.people
        .subscribe(people => this.people = people);
      }
```

However, what I really want is for the `Service` to return an `Array of Model` objects that was created from the data that the `Service` retrieved from the database. I realized that the `Component` could just create this array in the subscribe method, but I think it would be cleaner if the service do that and make it available to the `Component`.

How can the `Service` create a new `Observable`, containing that array, and return that?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

**UPDATE: 9/24/16 Angular 2.0 Stable**

This question gets a lot of traffic still, so, I wanted to update it. With the insanity of changes from Alpha, Beta, and 7 RC candidates, I stopped updating my SO answers until they went stable.

This is the perfect case for using [Subjects](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md) and [ReplaySubjects](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md)

I *personally* prefer to use `ReplaySubject(1)` as it allows the last stored value to be passed when new subscribers attach even when late:

```typescript
let project = new ReplaySubject(1);

//subscribe
project.subscribe(result => console.log('Subscription Streaming:', result));

http.get('path/to/whatever/projects/1234').subscribe(result => {
    //push onto subject
    project.next(result));

    //add delayed subscription AFTER loaded
    setTimeout(()=> project.subscribe(result => console.log('Delayed Stream:', result)), 3000);
});

//Output
//Subscription Streaming: 1234
//*After load and delay*
//Delayed Stream: 1234
```

So even if I attach late or need to load later I can always get the latest call and not worry about missing the callback.

This also lets you use the same stream to push down onto:

```
project.next(5678);
//output
//Subscription Streaming: 5678
```

But what if you are 100% sure, that you only need to do the call once? Leaving open subjects and observables isn't good but there's always that **"What If?"**

That's where [AsyncSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/asyncsubject.md) comes in.

```typescript
let project = new AsyncSubject();

//subscribe
project.subscribe(result => console.log('Subscription Streaming:', result),
                  err => console.log(err),
                  () => console.log('Completed'));

http.get('path/to/whatever/projects/1234').subscribe(result => {
    //push onto subject and complete
    project.next(result));
    project.complete();

    //add a subscription even though completed
    setTimeout(() => project.subscribe(project => console.log('Delayed Sub:', project)), 2000);
});

//Output
//Subscription Streaming: 1234
//Completed
//*After delay and completed*
//Delayed Sub: 1234
```

Awesome! Even though we closed the subject it still replied with the last thing it loaded.

Another thing is how we subscribed to that http call and handled the response. [Map](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/select.md) is great to process the response.

```
public call = http.get(whatever).map(res => res.json())
```

But what if we needed to nest those calls? Yes you could use subjects with a special function:

```typescript
getThing() {
    resultSubject = new ReplaySubject(1);

    http.get('path').subscribe(result1 => {
        http.get('other/path/' + result1).get.subscribe(response2 => {
            http.get('another/' + response2).subscribe(res3 => resultSubject.next(res3))
        })
    })
    return resultSubject;
}
var myThing = getThing();
```

But that's a lot and means you need a function to do it. Enter [FlatMap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md):

```typescript
var myThing = http.get('path').flatMap(result1 => 
                    http.get('other/' + result1).flatMap(response2 => 
                        http.get('another/' + response2)));
```

Sweet, the `var` is an observable that gets the data from the final http call.

**OK thats great but I want an angular2 service!**

I got you:

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {

  public activeProject:ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  //load the project
  public load(projectId) {
    console.log('Loading Project:' + projectId, Date.now());
    this.http.get('/projects/' + projectId).subscribe(res => this.activeProject.next(res));
    return this.activeProject;
  }

 }

 //component

@Component({
    selector: 'nav',
    template: `<div>{{project?.name}}<a (click)="load('1234')">Load 1234</a></div>`
})
 export class navComponent implements OnInit {
    public project:any;

    constructor(private projectService:ProjectService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.projectService.activeProject.subscribe(active => this.project = active);
    }

    public load(projectId:string) {
        this.projectService.load(projectId);
    }

 }
```

I'm a big fan of observers and observables so I hope this update helps!

**Original Answer**

I think this is a use case of using a [Observable Subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md) or in `Angular2` the `EventEmitter`.

In your service you create a `EventEmitter` that allows you to push values onto it. In **Alpha 45** you have to convert it with `toRx()`, but I know they were working to get rid of that, so in **Alpha 46** you may be able to simply return the `EvenEmitter`.

```typescript
class EventService {
  _emitter: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  rxEmitter: any;
  constructor() {
    this.rxEmitter = this._emitter.toRx();
  }
  doSomething(data){
    this.rxEmitter.next(data);
  }
}
```

This way has the single `EventEmitter` that your different service functions can now push onto.

If you wanted to return an observable directly from a call you could do something like this:

```js
myHttpCall(path) {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        http.get(path).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((result) => {
            //do something with result. 
            var newResultArray = mySpecialArrayFunction(result);
            observer.next(newResultArray);
            //call complete if you want to close this stream (like a promise)
            observer.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

That would allow you do this in the component:
`peopleService.myHttpCall('path').subscribe(people => this.people = people);`

And mess with the results from the call in your service.

I like creating the `EventEmitter` stream on its own in case I need to get access to it from other components, but I could see both ways working...

Here's a plunker that shows a basic service with an event emitter: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DAsLAT?p=info)

Comment: I tried this approach but got "Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature" -error.  Anyone have an idea of what to do?

Comment: @Spock the spec has seemed to update since this original question. You no longer need the "new" for the observable as it does this for you. Simply remove the new and let me know what happens. I'm messing with some stuff now, if it works for you as well I'll update this answer

Comment: Using `EventEmitter` for anything but `@Output()` is discouraged. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Yes it is now... At the time it was going to be EventEmitters all over but they've since standardized on Rx Observables. My Observable example still works but if you were going to use the EventEmitter example I gave I suggest using Subjects directly: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md

Comment: @maxisam Thanks for the edit, although the answer was/is relative to the Alpha removing "new" for the Observable is correct now

Comment: Hmmm, why I can't do this code  let project = new ReplaySubject(1);
project.subscribe(result => console.log('Subscription Streaming:', result)); into Service ? project is undefined in this case;

Comment: @EugeneShmorgun you should be able to. It would be just like adding `this.activeProject.subscribe(result => console.log(result))` to the service.

Comment: I tried to get the code running but i receive "Cannot read property 'next' of undefined" error at this line "this.http.get('/projects/' + projectId).subscribe(res => this.activeProject.next(res));"

Comment: are you setting this.activeProject as a ReplaySubject? It's saying you haven't defined it...

Comment: Just an FYI, you can use ` new BehaviorSubject<T>(initialValue)` in place of `new ReplaySubject(1)`, but just be aware that a `BehaviorSubject` requires an initial value

Comment: What about the subscription in the service, how would we ensure that gets closed? Wouldn't this approach just potentially keep tons of subscriptions open inside services?

Comment: @Johannes, In the examples I gave I used an AsyncSubject which closes, the http's close automatically as well. Yes, you leave open a stream but that's the point anyway. You want to be able to pull from it at any time.

Comment: Why load() function in ProjectService needs to return the Subject ? #JustCurious

Comment: @BeingSuman because we don't know when exactly the call will return. You could return the call itself but I generally like to return the main thread.

Answer (score 31):

This is an example from [Angular2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) of how you can create and use your own Observables :

**The Service**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'
import {Subject}    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class MissionService {
  private _missionAnnouncedSource = new Subject<string>();
  missionAnnounced$ = this._missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();

  announceMission(mission: string) {
    this._missionAnnouncedSource.next(mission)
  }
}
```

**The Component**

```
    import {Component}          from 'angular2/core';
    import {MissionService}     from './mission.service';

    export class MissionControlComponent {
      mission: string;

      constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {

        missionService.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(
          mission => {
            this.mission = mission;
          })
      }

      announce() {
        this.missionService.announceMission('some mission name');
      }
    }
```

Full and working example can be found here :
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 23):

I would like to add that if the object that is created is static and not coming through http something like that can be done:

```
public fetchModel(uuid: string = undefined): Observable<string> {
      if(!uuid) { //static data
        return Observable.of(new TestModel()).map(o => JSON.stringify(o));
      }
      else {
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/model/" + uuid)
                .map(res => res.text());
      }
    }
```

**Edit:**
For Angular 7.x.x mapping needs to be done using pipe() as described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54085359/986160):

```
import {of,  Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
[...]
public fetchModel(uuid: string = undefined): Observable<string> {
      if(!uuid) { //static data
        return of(new TestModel());
      }
      else {
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/model/" + uuid)
                .pipe(map((res:any) => res)) //already contains json
      }
    }
```

from answer to my question about observers and static data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35219772/986160

Comment: worked for me by using of, thanks you saved my day.

Answer (score 19):

I'm a little late to the party, but I think my approach has the advantage that it lacks the use of EventEmitters and Subjects.

So, here's my approach. We can't get away from subscribe(), and we don't want to. In that vein, our service will return an `Observable<T>` with an observer that has our precious cargo. From the caller, we'll initialize a variable, `Observable<T>`, and it will get the service's `Observable<T>`. Next, we'll subscribe to this object. Finally, you get your "T"! from your service.

First, our people service, but yours doesnt pass parameters, that's more realistic:

```
people(hairColor: string): Observable<People> {
   this.url = "api/" + hairColor + "/people.json";

   return Observable.create(observer => {
      http.get(this.url)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe((data) => {
             this._people = data

             observer.next(this._people);
             observer.complete();


          });
   });
}
```

Ok, as you can see, we're returning an `Observable` of type "people".  The signature of the method, even says so!  We tuck-in the `_people` object into our observer.  We'll access this type from our caller in the Component, next!

In the Component:

```
private _peopleObservable: Observable<people>;

constructor(private peopleService: PeopleService){}

getPeople(hairColor:string) {
   this._peopleObservable = this.peopleService.people(hairColor);

   this._peopleObservable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.people = data;
   });
}
```

We initialize our `_peopleObservable` by returning that `Observable<people>` from our `PeopleService`.  Then, we subscribe to this property.  Finally, we set `this.people` to our data(`people`) response.

Architecting the service in this fashion has one, major advantage over the typical service: map(...) and component: "subscribe(...)" pattern.  In the real world, we need to map the json to our properties in our class and, sometimes, we do some custom stuff there.  So this mapping can occur in our service.  And, typically, because our service call will be used not once, but, probably, in other places in our code, we don't have to perform that mapping in some component, again. Moreover, what if we add a new field to people?....

Comment: I agree that the formatting should be in the service and I posted a standard Observable method too but the advantage of Subjects in a service is that other functions can trigger on it. If you're always only needing the direct http call then I'd use the Observable method..

Answer (score 11):

In the service.ts file -

a. import 'of' from observable/of
 b. create a json list
 c. return json object using Observable.of()
    Ex. -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class ClientListService {
    private clientList;

    constructor() {
        this.clientList = [
            {name: 'abc', address: 'Railpar'},
            {name: 'def', address: 'Railpar 2'},
            {name: 'ghi', address: 'Panagarh'},
            {name: 'jkl', address: 'Panagarh 2'},
        ];
    }

    getClientList () {
        return Observable.of(this.clientList);
    }
};
```

In the component where we are calling the get function of the service -

```
this.clientListService.getClientList().subscribe(res => this.clientList = res);
```

Comment: Good work @Anirban, could also only return of(this.clientList);

Answer (score 7):

Notice that you're using [Observable#map](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/select.md) to convert the raw `Response` object your base Observable emits to a parsed representation of the JSON response.

If I understood you correctly, you want to `map` again. But this time, converting that raw JSON to instances of your `Model`. So you would do something like:

```
http.get('api/people.json')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(peopleData => peopleData.map(personData => new Person(personData)))
```

So, you started with an Observable that emits a `Response` object, turned that into an observable that emits an object of the parsed JSON of that response, and then turned that into yet another observable that turned that raw JSON into an array of your models.