# How to create an Observable from static data similar to http one in Angular?

Tags: typescript, promise, angular, observable, rxjs

I am having a service that has this method:

```
export class TestModelService {

    public testModel: TestModel;

    constructor( @Inject(Http) public http: Http) {
    }

    public fetchModel(uuid: string = undefined): Observable<string> {
        if(!uuid) {
            //return Observable of JSON.stringify(new TestModel());
        }
        else {
            return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/model/" + uuid)
                .map(res => res.text());
        }
    }
}
```

in the component's constructor I am subscribing like this:

```
export class MyComponent {
   testModel: TestModel;
   testModelService: TestModelService;

   constructor(@Inject(TestModelService) testModelService) {
      this.testModelService = testModelService;

      testService.fetchModel("29f4fddc-155a-4f26-9db6-5a431ecd5d44").subscribe(
          data => { this.testModel = FactModel.fromJson(JSON.parse(data)); },
          err => console.log(err)
      );
   }
}
```

This works if an object comes from the server but I am trying to create an observable that will work with the given `subscribe()` call for a static string (this happens when `testModelService.fetchModel()` does not receive an uuid) so there is seamless handling in both cases.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Perhaps you could try to use the [`of`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/of.md) method of the `Observable` class:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

public fetchModel(uuid: string = undefined): Observable<string> {
  if(!uuid) {
    return Observable.of(new TestModel()).map(o => JSON.stringify(o));
  }
  else {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/model/" + uuid)
            .map(res => res.text());
  }
}
```

Comment: That was awesome! It worked! I was trying many things like Observable.from() etc.. The API documentation for Observable isn't the cleanest/most user-friendly at this point! Thanks :)

Comment: One thing if you're using version 6, you've to `import { of } from 'rxjs';` and use `of`, instead of `Observable.of`.

Comment: For Angular v7.x.x there is no `.map()` on the result of get so you need to do `.pipe(map((res:any) => res.json()))`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35220045/986160

Answer (score 131):

As of July 2018 and the release of `RxJS 6`, the new way to get an Observable from a value is to import the `of` operator like so:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

and then create the observable from the value, like so:

```
of(someValue);
```

Note, that you used to have to do `Observable.of(someValue)` like in the currently accepted answer. There is a good article on the other RxJS 6 changes [here](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/).

Answer (score 23):

Things seem to have changed since Angular 2.0.0

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs/Subscriber';
// ...
public fetchModel(uuid: string = undefined): Observable<string> {
  if(!uuid) {
    return new Observable<TestModel>((subscriber: Subscriber<TestModel>) => subscriber.next(new TestModel())).map(o => JSON.stringify(o));
  }
  else {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/model/" + uuid)
            .map(res => res.text());
  }
}
```

The `.next()` function will be called on your subscriber.

Comment: I have migrated to Angular 2.1.2.. The old way seems to be still supported.. Could you please elaborate why this is a better solution or is it the convention? I will then change it in all the places in my code and I will re-accept ..Thanks

Comment: @MichailMichailidis, with a month of retrospect, it seems to me both are equally valid, the main difference being that Thierry's solution requires you to import the `of` function of rxjs, like `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'`

Answer (score 14):

This is how you can create a simple observable for static data.

```
let observable = Observable.create(observer => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let users = [
      {username:"balwant.padwal",city:"pune"},
      {username:"test",city:"mumbai"}]

    observer.next(users); // This method same as resolve() method from Angular 1
    console.log("am done");
    observer.complete();//to show we are done with our processing
    // observer.error(new Error("error message"));
  }, 2000);

})

to subscribe to it is very easy

observable.subscribe((data)=>{
  console.log(data); // users array display
});
```

I hope this answer is helpful. We can use HTTP call instead static data.

Comment: can you update the typo from observable.subscripe to observable.subscribe

Answer (score 6):

As of May 2021 the new way to get an Observable from a value is:

importing:

```js
import "rxjs/add/observable/of"
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"
```

and using it, like so::

```js
Observable.of(your_value)
```

Answer (score 3):

This way you can create Observable from data, in my case I need to maintain shopping cart:

**service.ts**

```
export class OrderService {
    cartItems: BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    cartItems$ = this.cartItems.asObservable();

    // I need to maintain cart, so add items in cart

    addCartData(data) {
        const currentValue = this.cartItems.value; // get current items in cart
        const updatedValue = [...currentValue, data]; // push new item in cart

        if(updatedValue.length) {
          this.cartItems.next(updatedValue); // notify to all subscribers
        }
      }
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class CartViewComponent implements OnInit {
    cartProductList: any = [];
    constructor(
        private order: OrderService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.order.cartItems$.subscribe(items => {
            this.cartProductList = items;
        });
    }
}
```