# RxJs: Create observable from field value changing

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'd like to create an `Observable` using as source a variables: `this.pending`.

I want to create an Observable which generates a feed every time `this.pending` value changes.

I mean, when I do:

```
this.pending = false;
```

in some place of my code, I want to receive a `false` feed on my subscription, and so on...

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35219772/4826457

Comment: Use a reactive form

Comment: Any example over internet?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `BehaviorSubject`.

```
this.pending = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)
```

and somewhere

```
subscription = this.pending.subscribe(console.log)
```

Then every time you execute

`this.pending.next(true)` or `this.pending.next(false)`

`subscription` gets new value from `this.pending`.