# How to bind & convert static inline JSON object to an Angular 4 observable

Tags: json, angular, typescript

We get observable as a return type with http.get request. UI elements can be binded with this observable collection. In my case I am not sending any http request. There is a predefined JSON in my js file and I want bind it on the UI.

I used JSON.parse to get the JSON object from JSON string. I get the JSON object. Can anybody tell how to convert this JSON object into observable collection which can be binded with UI.

Comment: is it a json array (array of objects) or a json object?

Comment: share your json and some code

Comment: Maybe this helps: Observable.of... See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219713/how-to-create-an-observable-from-static-data-similar-to-http-one-in-angular)