# observable with harcoded data

Tags: angular, rxjs

i am working with an angular application in version 10. Below requirement to learn observables with hardcoded json objects with no http calls. For example i have a interface

```
export interface cities {
cityId: number;
cityName: string;
}
```

Below is the code where i declare an observable

```
cities$: Observable<city[]>;
```

in the Oninit Method i create objects like this

```
ngOnInit() : void {
 const cityData = [
  {
     cityId: 1,
     cityName: 'Bangalore'
  },
  {
    cityId: 2,
    cityName: 'chennai'
  }
];

// here i want to get the values in the observables. how can i do it
   this.cities$ = ...
}
```

below is the html code

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let city of cities$ | async'>
     <span [innerHTML] = 'city.cityName'>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an Observable from static data similar to http one in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219713/how-to-create-an-observable-from-static-data-similar-to-http-one-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rxjs `of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) operator like this:

```
this.cities$ = of(this.cityData);
```

You will need to import the operator first:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```