# Angular 2 - update view/component

Tags: angular

I have a component with `ngOnInit()` and a `login()` method.

How can I update the component and execute my ngOnInit methods again after the login is done?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this._guestService.getAllGuests()
        .subscribe(
            guests => this.guests = guests,
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('Request Complete')
         )
}  

login() {
    this.auth.login();
}
logout() {
    this.auth.logout();
}
```

`auth.login` service:

```
 login() {
   this.lock.show((error: string, profile: Object, id_token: string) => {
     if (error) {
       console.log(error);
     }
     localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
     localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);
   });
 }
```

Comment: The code in `ngOnInit()` doesn't seem to depend on the current login status. Why do you want `ngOnInit()` to be executed again?

Answer (score 1):

I would rename `ngOnInit()` something like `getAllGuests()` and then call `getAllGuests()` from within `ngOnInit()` and from within `auth.login()`.

If you can't or do not want to insert this call in  `auth.login()` I guess the thing could become a little more subtle and would require some sort of subscription mechanism using Observables, but before starting this path I would make sure you really need it.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension to Picci's answer, I would call getAllGuests on subscribe of login():

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.getAllGuests();
    }

    getAllGuests() {
        this.loading = true;
        this._guestService.getAllGuests()
            .subscribe(
                guests => this.guests = guests,
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('Request Complete')
             )
    }  

    login() {
        this.auth.login().subscribe(()=> this.getAllGuests());
    }
    logout() {
        this.auth.logout();
    }
```

Comment: so my `this.auth.login()` service has to return a success from the login with an observable?

Comment: it has to return Observable. check this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675155/creating-and-returning-observable-from-angular-2-service

Comment: can you give me an advice how can I fire the 'getAllGuestd' method AFTER the login was successful?

Comment: Call 'getAllGuestId()' in the subscribe of login. This will make sure it's called after login is complete/successful.