# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

I am trying to call an API from Angular but am getting this error:

`Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'`

The answers from this similar question didn't solve my issue: [Angular 2 beta.17: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947748/angular-2-beta-17-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse).

I am using Angular 2.0.0-beta.17.

Answer (score 486, accepted):

You need to import the `map` operator:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

Or more generally:

```ts
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

---

Notice: For versions of RxJS `6.x.x` and above, you will have to use pipeable operators as shown in the code snippet below:

```ts
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

// ...
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getItems() {
    this.http.get('https://example.com/api/items').pipe(map(data => {})).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
}
```

This is caused by the RxJS team removing support for using 
See the [breaking changes](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-7) in RxJS' changelog for more info.

From the changelog:

> **operators**: Pipeable operators must now be imported from rxjs like so: `import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';`. No deep imports.

Comment: Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. 

Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.

Comment: How do you import the `Observable` class? Like this: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';` or `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';`?

Comment: i am not import this class so far

Comment: Okay you use observables indirectly. I think that it's a problem related to your version of rxjs. See https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/issues/81. Could you give versions of Angular2 and Rxjs you use?

Comment: angular 2.0.0-beta*17 and rxjs 25.0.0-beta7

Comment: I think that you use rxjs 5.0.0-beta2 with angular2 beta17.

Comment: I am using Angular 2 RC1 and rxjs 5.0.0-beta2. I have imported Observable as import {Observable} from 'rxjs/observable'; and imported map operator like import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; It was working when I was using Beta 7. I just upgraded to RC1 and it broke.

Comment: There have been more changes, see this page: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: Yes, I'm using Angular6 and syntax from this post now works for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50527873/angular-6-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-object

Comment: First write this command in vs code terminal of your project and restart the project. `npm install rxjs-compat` , than import the `map` operator.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Using Angular9 the same code of yours (changing url of course) it give me 'undefined'. Url return a json result if you try to put on browser

Comment: I have the operator imported but stil lsee the message when I run ng test

Answer (score 218):

Revisiting this because my solution isn't listed here.

I am running Angular 6 with rxjs 6.0 and ran into this error.

Here's what I did to fix it:

I changed

```
map((response: any) => response.json())
```

to simply be:

```
.pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
```

I found the fix here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15548#issuecomment-387009186

Comment: I'm not sure why the migration tool rxjs-5-to-6-migrate doesn't pick this up? It's interesting that it doesn't address the do/tap re-mapping which in my environment is still unresolved even though the import tool recognizes it. 90% of my 'unanticipated wasted time' in Angular development is spent with RxJS document and code boundary issues, this is really frustrating.

Comment: Thank you! You are a lifesaver!! Whoever is interested, the full reference to this change is available here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax

Comment: This worked for me, I also needed to add `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Funny, this is exactly how we fixed it on angular 6 upgrade - which brought the latest rxjs too.

Comment: @paul Thanks. Regarding `.catch`, we can use `catchError` like `.pipe(catchError(this.handleError))` ?

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow   , thanks for answer about catchError. I use it after ı solved another problem :)

Answer (score 72):

Just write this command in the VS Code terminal of your project and restart the project.

```
npm install rxjs-compat
```

You need to import the `map` operator by adding this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Comment: if it does not work close all the files and restart the vs studio.

Answer (score 42):

For the Angular 7v

Change

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

To

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
```

And

```
 return this.http.get('http://localhost/ionicapis/public/api/products')
 .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
```

Comment: it helped me @Katana24 as I saw the correct syntax with pipe.

Comment: that solution works good in angular 10 where not need to install rxjs-compat that will give warnings like 'Fix CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts'

Comment: How do you access the JSON object through this? When i try to print the JSON string with console.log(), I only get a Observable<Any> object?

Comment: This is the way to go with Angular 12, apparently. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue with Angular 2.0.1 because I was importing Observable from

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

I resolve my problem on importing Observable from this path instead

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: This practice is considered not bundle-size-friendly since that statement imports all operators of `Observable` (including the ones that you don't use) into the bundle.

Instead, you should import each operator individually. I recommend using "lettable operators", which was introduced in RxJS v5.5 to support better tree-shaking.

Answer (score 20):

In rxjs 6 map operator usage has been changed 
now you need to Use it like this.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
myObservable
  .pipe(map(data => data * 2))
  .subscribe(...);
```

For reference 
https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/#operators-update-path

Comment: Take note of this answer as anyone doing `RxJS v6` will need to use the `.pipe()` or none of the operators will work directly off the Observable. You'll see an error like, `Property 'share' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'`

Answer (score 12):

In new version of httpClient module in angular, you have not yet to write it this way:

```
return this.http.request(request)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

but do it this way:

```
return this.http.request(request)
             .pipe(
               map((res: any) => res.json())
             );
```

Answer (score 11):

In the latest *Angular 7.*.**, you can try this simply as:

```
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { map, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
```

And then you can use these `methods` as follows:

```
   private getHtml(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("../../assets/test-data/preview.html").pipe(
      map((res: any) => res.json()),
      catchError(<T>(error: any, result?: T) => {
        console.log(error);
        return of(result as T);
      })
    );
  }
```

Check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-local-file?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for more details.

Answer (score 8):

just install rxjs-compat by typing in terminal:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

then import :

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

getGetFunction(){
this.http.get('http://someapi')
.pipe(map(res => res));
}

getPostFunction(yourPara){
this.http.get('http://someapi',yourPara)
.pipe(map(res => res));
}
```

In above function you can see i didn't use res.json() since im using HttpClient. It applies res.json() automatically and returns Observable (HttpResponse < string>). You no longer need to call this function yourself after angular 4 in HttpClient.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it wouldn't enough to include only map and promise:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

I solved this problem by importing several rxjs components as [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#enable-rxjs-operators) recommends:

1) Import statements in one app/rxjs-operators.ts file:

```
// import 'rxjs/Rx'; // adds ALL RxJS statics & operators to Observable

// See node_module/rxjs/Rxjs.js
// Import just the rxjs statics and operators we need for THIS app.

// Statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

2) Import rxjs-operator itself in your service:

```
// Add the RxJS Observable operators we need in this app.
import './rxjs-operators';
```

Comment: I feel its not right to include rxjs-operators in every services. It should be included only at app.module.ts but unfortunately ng test throws error if operators are not imported in specific places

Answer (score 4):

In **Angular v10.x** and **rxjs v6.x**

First import map top of my service,

`import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';`

Then I use map like this

```
return this.http.get<return type>(URL)
  .pipe(map(x => {
    // here return your pattern
    return x.foo;
  }));
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I was using Visual studio 2015 which had an older version of typescript.

After upgrading the extension the issue got resolved.

[Download Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593)

Answer (score 3):

I am using Angular 5.2 and when I use `import 'rxjs/Rx';` it throws me the following lint error:
***TSLint: This import is blacklisted, import a submodule instead (import-blacklist)***

See the screenshot below:
[image: Import of rxjs/Rx is blacklisted in Angular 5.2]

**SOLUTION:**
Solved it by **importing only the operators that I needed**. Example follows:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

So the fix would be to import specifically only the necessary operators.

Comment: @AndrewBenjamin I highly suggest that you do that. That will save you a lot of trouble down the lane.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same error. One solution that worked for me was to add the following lines in your **service.ts** file **instead** of `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

For an example, my **app.service.ts** after debugging was like,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=Warren,OH&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22')
        .pipe(map(result => result));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `map` function in `pipe` function and it will solve your problem.
You can check the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md).

```
this.items = this.afs.collection('blalal').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
  return changes.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Items;
    data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return data;
  })
}))
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply install **rxjs-compat** to solve the problem

```
npm i rxjs-compat --save-dev
```

And import it like below

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all run installation as below:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat@6
```

Now you need to import `rxjs` in `service.ts`:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Voila! The problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

simply run `npm install --save rxjs-compat` it fixes the error.

[It is recommended here](https://github.com/webmaxru/pwa-workshop-angular/issues/2)

Comment: Please don't forget to import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the possible answers posted above none of them worked,

> I resolved it by simply restarting my IDE i.e., Visual Studio Code

May it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

If after importing import 'rxjs/add/operator/map' or import 'rxjs/Rx' too you are getting the same error then restart your visual studio code editor, the error will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

for all those linux users that are having this problem, check if the rxjs-compat folder is locked. I had this exact same issue and I went in terminal, used the sudo su to give permission to the whole rxjs-compat folder and it was fixed. Thats assuming you imported

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

in the project.ts file where the original .map error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to https://github.com/nagamallabhanu

https://github.com/webmaxru/pwa-workshop-angular/issues/2#issuecomment-395024755

encapsulating

> pipe(map(....))

worked

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

courseRef: AngularFireList<any>;
courses$: Observable<any[]>;

this.courseRef = db.list('/tags');
  this.courses$ = this.courseRef.snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() 
  }));
 }));
 this.courses$.subscribe(res=>{
   console.log(res)
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http } from '@angular/http';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class RestfulService {

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

 //access apis Get Request 
 getUsers() {
 return this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .map(res => res.json());
  }

 }
```

run the command

```
 npm install rxjs-compat
```

I just import

```
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

**restart the vs code, issue solved.**

Answer (score 0):

Angular 9:

```
 forkJoin([
  this.http.get().pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      return of([]);
    })
  ),
  this.http.get().pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      return of([]);
    })
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this old way to get route params

```
 this._route.params
        .map(params => params['id'])
```

To updated it for new rxjs version

First,
import the map from rxjs operators.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Second add pipe,

```
   this._route.params.pipe(
            map(params => params['id']))
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem i solve it as follow

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; // imports statement 

return this.auth.user$.pipe(
  map(user =>{
    if(user) return true;
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: {returnUrl :state.url}});
    return false;
  }));
}
```

There was a problem with observable type which was null so i add type any and it helped to clear many errors

```
user$: Observable<firebase.User | any>;
```

Answer (score -1):

The angular new version does not support .map you have to install this through cmd
npm install --save rxjs-compat
via this you can enjoy with old technique .
note:
don't forget to import these lines.

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Comment: This late answer is redundant.