# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>' when using angular version 2.4.9, typescript & webpack version 2.2.1

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, webpack

I am trying to access web api methods from Angular 2 application, i am able to get the records using web api. But the problem is, service.ts file showing **Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'** error.

Sample Code:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';

    @Injectable()
    export class ContactServices 

    {

        private url = 'http://localhost:51498/api/test/';
        constructor(private http: Http) { }

        getContacts():Observable<Object[]> {
            return this.http.get(this.url + 'GetContacts')
                .map(response => response.json())
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    return Observable.throw(error);
                });
        }

        getContactById(id: number) {
            return this.http.get(this.url + 'GetContactList/' + id)
                .map(response => <Contact[]>response.json())
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    return Observable.throw(error);
                });
        }
    }

export class Contact {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Details: string;
}
```

I am using below versions,

1. webpack 2.2.1
2. angular 2.4.9
3. node 6.10.0
4. npm 4.1.2
5. typescript 2.2.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208801/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse)

Comment: @ranakrunal9.. Op has already imported `rxjs/Rx`

Comment: i have tried using 'rxjs/Rx' and 'rxjs/add/operator/map' still it's showing error

Comment: Are you sure you have put *all* relevant code? I dont see `Contact` import..

Comment: I have put all relevant codes and also i am able to access DB records using web api. Contact is just a model object which is                                          export class Contact {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Details: string;
}

Comment: @VenkateswaranR I assume you have defined the response you are getting in the component like `Contact[]` but you are returning an `Observable<Object[]>` try to change that to `Observable<Contact[]>` if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **TypeScript** version. I have mentioned that, it is **2.2.1** version but my system is having **1.8.3** version. So only the problem occur. Thanks for who and all reviewing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using vs code and this problem was solved by update typescript version in `package.json`.

- step 1: `npm install -g typescript@latest`
- step 2: check typescript version: `tsc --v`
- step 3: Update typescript version in `package.json` to the version got
  from step 2.

Works for me.