# Despite proper imports of rxjs, property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a MEAN stack app using Angular 2.

I know that this question has been asked multiple times on StackOverflow.  I've been researching the questions and trying the different suggestions.  For most people, importing the entire rx/js library and map, or importing:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

seems to solve the issue.  I have been trying different combinations of this, to no avail.  I keep getting the error on all instances of .map in my service.  I tried updating my global typescript, as well as my typescript version being used in the dependencies.  I get the error in my terminal after 'ng serve'.  I think this is a typescript issue, but I am not sure - the error is a bit vague now that importing observables does not resolve it.

## Package.json

```
{
  "name": "aether-news",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.43",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.62",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.0",
    "amcharts3-angular2": "github:amcharts/amcharts3-angular2",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^2.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "tslint": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "upgrade": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

## Imports in my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

## service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class NewsApiService {

  public bingToken: string;
  public bbc: any;
  public bingWorld: any;
  public bingPolitics: any;
  public apNews: any;
  public googleNews: any;
  public economistNews: any;
  public nytNews: any;
  public wapoNews: any;
  public cnnNews: any;
  public newsweekNews: any;
  public reutersNews: any;
  public guardianUkNews: any;
  public guardianAuNews: any;
  public huffPostNews: any;
  public wsjNews: any;

  public eventRegistryBBC: any;
  public eventRegistryGuardian: any;
  public eventRegistryCNN: any;
  public eventRegistryWAPO: any;
  public eventRegistryReuters: any;
  public eventRegistryNYT: any;
  public eventRegistryEconomist: any;
  public eventRegistryAP: any;
  public eventRegistryWSJ: any;
  public eventRegistryNewswire: any;

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private router: Router
  ) {}


//EVENT REGISTRY
//BBC
getEventRegistryBBC(){
  return this.http.get("http://eventregistry.org/json/article?sourceUri=bbc.co.uk&sourceUri=bbc.com&categoryUri=dmoz%2FSociety%2FPolitics&action=getArticles&articlesSortBy=date&resultType=articles&articlesCount=200&articlesIncludeArticleDuplicateList=true&articlesIncludeArticleCategories=true&articlesIncludeConceptImage=true&articlesIncludeConceptDescription=true&articlesIncludeConceptDetails=true&articlesIncludeConceptTrendingScore=true&articlesIncludeSourceDescription=true&articlesIncludeArticleImage=true&articlesIncludeSourceDetails=true")
    .map((res) => {
      this.eventRegistryBBC = res.json()
      return res.json().articles.results;
    })
}
```

Very curious whether people have faced this same issue, even with proper imports of rxjs.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Could you add the code that is generating this error? Where you are using Observable<Response>?

Comment: hi @DeborahK, I added my service code.  Apologies, the file is quite long - I shortened it to just one API call.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693265/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse-when-using-angular)?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @SergeyKaravaev.  As I mentioned, I upgraded both my global typescript and the typescript version I am using in my dependencies, but still receive the same error.

Comment: And `import 'rxjs/Rx';` instead of `map` hasn't worked for you either?

Comment: Just to confirm, what do you see if you type `tsc -v` at the command prompt?

Comment: hi @Vandesh - I've tried 'rxjs/Rx' to no avail.

Comment: @DeborahK Version 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

In all of my services, they're typed (see Observable) and they don't have multiple returns - I'm not sure how/if that would work.

My services return this.http.get - etc - and map the response with response.json().

In my component I subscribe to the Observable and do any further data manipulations to extract the specific data.

Maybe try something like this?

```
getEventRegistryBBC(): Observable<Response>{
  return this.http.get("http://eventregistry.org/json/article?sourceUri=bbc.co.uk&sourceUri=bbc.com&categoryUri=dmoz%2FSociety%2FPolitics&action=getArticles&articlesSortBy=date&resultType=articles&articlesCount=200&articlesIncludeArticleDuplicateList=true&articlesIncludeArticleCategories=true&articlesIncludeConceptImage=true&articlesIncludeConceptDescription=true&articlesIncludeConceptDetails=true&articlesIncludeConceptTrendingScore=true&articlesIncludeSourceDescription=true&articlesIncludeArticleImage=true&articlesIncludeSourceDetails=true")
  .map(response => response.json())
}
```