# trying to map through a collection of docs results in error

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a to-do application with firebase and typescript.
I had this function that returns all the projects a current user has in it's list
but when it came to adding information to it, it became hard.

Eventually I find a way but it still wasn't good enough, but certainly not clean and efficient enough. So i used chatbot to optimize it and the response was clean and understandable, but I can't seem to get why I'm getting the error:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot'.

I have no clue what is wrong so maybe one of you can point it out..?

This is the function:

```
const returnProjects = async (id:string) => {
  const array: string[] = [];
  const list = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('#projectList');
  
  const projects = await getDocs(collection(db, 'projects'));
  const projectsUsersPromise = projects.map(async (doc: any) => ({
    users: await getCountFromServer(collection(db, `projects/${doc.id}/users`)),
    data: doc.data(),
  }));
  const projectsUsers = await Promise.all(projectsUsersPromise);
  
  projectsUsers.forEach((project: any) => {
    const amountUsers = project.users.data().count;
    const { name } = project.data();
    const newElement = document.createElement('div');
    if (list) list.appendChild(newElement).setAttribute('class', 'projectCard');
    newElement.innerHTML = `
        <h4>${name}</h4>
        <div id='cardBottom'>
          <div id='cardUsers'>
            <img src='/src/img/user.svg' alt='Users' width='12vw' id='projectUsers'>
            <span>${amountUsers}</span>
          </div>
          <img src='/src/img/info.svg' alt='Further information about this project' width='15vw' id='projectInfo'>
        </div>
      `; 
  });
};
```

Comment: The error is telling you that QuerySnapshot doesn't have a method called map.  If you want to learn what QuerySnapshot can do (it definitely can't do map), check the API reference (and don't depend on AI to write your code). https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node, firebase functions Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<QuerySnapshot>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019304/node-firebase-functions-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-promisequerysna)

Comment: It's so easy, copy error and paste it to google search engine end you have an answer. That's it, no more no less stack overflow with similar error pops up in google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Doug Stevenson according to [this Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#methods) `QuerySnapshot` does not have any map method If you want to use map method on `projects` you can use `projects.docs.map` then you will be mapping through the `Array<QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>>` which does have map method.

Alternatively you can also use `projects.forEach` but then you will lose the accumulation of promises like what you have done in map.

Here’s the updated code:

```
const returnProjects = async (id: string) => {
  const list = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('#projectList');

  const projects = await getDocs(collection(db, 'projects'));
  const projectsPromises = projects.docs.map(async (doc: any) => {
    const users = await getCountFromServer(collection(db, `projects/${doc.id}/users`));
    const { name } = doc.data();
    return { name, users: users.data().count };
  });
  const projectsData = await Promise.all(projectsPromises);

  projectsData.forEach((project: any) => {
    const newElement = document.createElement('div');
    if (list) list.appendChild(newElement).setAttribute('class', 'projectCard');
    newElement.innerHTML = `
        <h4>${project.name}</h4>
        <div id='cardBottom'>
          <div id='cardUsers'>
            <img src='/src/img/user.svg' alt='Users' width='12vw' id='projectUsers'>
            <span>${project.users}</span>
          </div>
          <img src='/src/img/info.svg' alt='Further information about this project' width='15vw' id='projectInfo'>
        </div>`; 
  });
};
```

Comment: I salute you for helping me out! Kudos to you