# Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

After I updated angular/cli, I got an error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'
```

[image]

I tried every possible solution from [Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208801/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but still the error exists.

Comment: You should paste your code here and not provide an image

Comment: that's my first question on stackoverflow.
i'll make sure to not repeat the mistake next time.

Comment: You can always edit your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its easy to post an answer when you provide your code instead of a screenshot. **Anyhow**, you have to `pipe` it:

```
getUsers() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl+'/show-users', this.options)
                     .pipe(
                          map((response:Response)=>response.json())
                      );
```

Remember to import `map` like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: getUsers(){
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl+'/show-users', this.options).pipe(map((response:Response)=>response.json()));
  }             

using .pipe() doest not resolve the issue.

Comment: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Answer (score 2):

For the latest Version of rxjs 
we need to install npm install rxjs-compat from terminal then declare

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution by using **pipe**. Here are the steps...

First import map

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Modify your getuser() and other all functions by using pipe

```
getUser(){
 this._http.get(this.baseUrl+'/show-users', this.options).pipe(map((response:Response)=>response.json()));                
}
```