# Not able to use map function

Tags: angular

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http,Headers } from '@angular/http';
     import { List } from '../models/List'
     import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
     import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

     @Injectable()
export class ListService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private serverApi= 'http://localhost:3000';

    public getAllLists():Observable<List[]> {

        let URI = `${this.serverApi}/bucketlist/`;
        return this.http.get(URI)
            .map(res => res.json())

            .map(res => <List[]>res.lists);
    }

    public deleteList(listId : string) {
      let URI = `${this.serverApi}/bucketlist/${listId}`;
        let headers = new Headers;
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.delete(URI, {headers})
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

i am getting error
Property map is not available on type Observable please anyone help

Comment: What rxjs version are you using ?

Comment: i am using 6.2.0 version of rxjs i have started coding again in angular after 2 months earlier it worked but now it shows error

Comment: why are you using `HttpModule` it is deprecated use `HttpClientModule` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503366/error-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observable)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you are using old syntax.

Do the following:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

then:

```
this.myObservableFunctionCall().pipe(map(data => {}))
```