# Why isn't my function returning the proper JSON data and how can I access it?

Tags: json, angular, httpclient

I'm running services to retrieve data from an API. Here is one of the services:

```
robotSummary(core_id, channel_name){
const params = new HttpParams()


var new_headers = {
  'access-token': ' '
};
this.access_token = sessionStorage.getItem('access-token');
new_headers['access-token'] = this.access_token;

const myObject: any = {core_id : core_id, channel_name: channel_name};
const httpParams: HttpParamsOptions = { fromObject: myObject } as HttpParamsOptions;

const options = { params: new HttpParams(httpParams), headers: new_headers };
return this.http.get(this.baseURL + 'web_app/robot_summary/',options)
.subscribe(
res => console.log(res),
        )
   }
}
```

The data shows up properly on the console, but I still can't access the individual keys: 
[image: console]

Here is how I call it:

```
ngOnInit(): void{

  this.login.getData(this.username, this.password).subscribe((data) => {
this.robotSummaryData = this.getRobotSummary.robotSummary(this.core_id, this.channel_name);
    console.log("robosummary"+ this.robotSummaryData)
  });
  }
```

When I call this function and assign it to a variable, it shows up on console as [object Object]. When I tried to use JSON.parse, it throws the error: type subscription is not assignable to parameter string. How can I access the data? I want to take the JSON object and save it as an Object with appropriate attributes. Thanks!

Comment: Assign what specifically to a variable? Is this just the normal async issue?

Comment: I want to assign for example the "state" key as an attribute to an object. I don't understand what you mean by normal async issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not subscribe inside your service, do subscribe in your component, change your service as follows,

```
robotSummary(core_id, channel_name){
    const params = new HttpParams()
    var new_headers = {
        'access-token': ' '
    };
    this.access_token = sessionStorage.getItem('access-token');
    new_headers['access-token'] = this.access_token; const myObject: any = { core_id: core_id, channel_name: channel_name };
    const httpParams: HttpParamsOptions = { fromObject: myObject } as HttpParamsOptions;

    const options = { params: new HttpParams(httpParams), headers: new_headers };
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + 'web_app/robot_summary/', options)
        .map((response: Response) => response);
}
```

and then in your component,

```
ngOnInit(){
        this.api..getRobotSummary.robotSummary(this.core_id, this.channel_name).subscribe((data) => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(this.data); 
});
}
```

Comment: I get the error: property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Comment: you need to import import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Comment: Tried that, still shows same error.. I also need the login call to finish executing before any of the other calls begin

Comment: what is the angular version

Comment: angular version 6.0.7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503366/error-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observable

Comment: I used the import statement in that answer, as well as tried to pipe it. still throws the same error :(

Comment: Okay I had some syntax wrong - I got the map function working. What type of variable is data? it's giving me an error in app.component file

Comment: use .subscribe((data:any)