# Item is deleted, but when you leave the page and come back the item is placed again even if it is not in the postman

Tags: angular

I'm developing an angled and php application and I'm running it all on localhost. on my front end I have a function that retrieves my information and displays. each line in the list has a button called delete to be able to delete this item, when I click on delete I get the id of the item and send a delete request to my server. I follow this along with the postman and it is possible to visualize that it really deletes all the files, but in my angular the item is still there, even though I remove it from the list when I try to retrieve the list using the method get the deleted item back but in the postman does not return.

**Category.service.ts**

```
  get(page, descricao) {
    page = 'all';
    return this.http.get(Auth.url + this.nameClass + `?page=${page}&desc=${descricao}`, { headers: { 'token': Auth.token } });
  }

  delete(id) {
    console.log(Auth.url + this.nameClass + "/" + id);
    this.http
      .delete(Auth.url + this.nameClass + "/" + id, { headers: { 'token': Auth.token } })
      .subscribe(dados => alert('Ok'), (error: any) => alert('erro'));
  }
```

When I use a function to delete the alert ('ok'), since my server returns true because it deleted perfectly

**CategoryList.Component.ts**

```
items: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.getList();
}

 excluir(desc, id) {

    if (confirm("Do you want to delete the category " + desc + " ?")) {
      let index = this.getIndex(id);
      if (index == -1)
        alert('Error');
      else {
        let result = this.categoriaService.delete(id);
        this.items.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  getIndex(id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++)
      if (this.items[i].id == id)
        return i;
    return -1;
  }

  getList(page: number = 1) {

     this.categoriaService.get(page, this.pesquisarValue)
.subscribe(dados => this.exibeLista(dados), (error: any) => console.log(error));
      }



  exibeLista(dados) {

    this.items = null;

    if (dados.result.count == 0) // Quantidade de itens retornados da consulta
      this.pages = null;
    else {
      if (dados.result.paginas == 0) // Quantidade de paginas
        this.pages = null;
      else {
        this.totalPages = dados.result.paginas;
        this.loadPages();
      }
      this.items = dados.result.item;
    }
```

I use the this.items.splice (index, 1) function; and removes the deleted item from my array of items, so far so good. when I leave this page and come back, the item is there again, even though it is not in postman.
I am using the extension in the chrome of allow-control-allow-origin will this cause any problems? Is this my list in some cache? how can I delete data that has been deleted

Comment: please don't tag a question with both [tag:angular] and [tag:angularjs] unless you truly are doing a mixed framework project;  **These are not the same framework**.

Comment: Hello, I'm new to angular and I'm going through this same problem. on the server the item is removed, but when the function is called to retrieve it back. however if you try to delete it again it returns as if it had already been deleted

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking good except the service .Please change your service code as below

```
get(page, descricao) {
    page = 'all';
    return this.http.get(Auth.url + this.nameClass + `?page=${page}&desc=${descricao}`, { headers: { 'token': Auth.token } })
.map(response => return response ) // or try  `response.json()` instead of `response` 
.catch(error => {
     return Observable.throw(error);
   });;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use your method and the following error is displayed: "Map property does not exist in type Observable", my imports import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: @EmiryMirella  Just import `import 'rxjs/Rx';`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208801/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse

Comment: My angle is version 6. I did it, but still the error "ERROR in node_modules / rxjs / Rx.d.ts (1.15): error TS2307: Can not find module 'rxjs-compat' still exists.
src / app / model / category.service.ts (35,6): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable <Object>'. "

Comment: Then you should fix the error. Because every service call we need to be use the `map()` for observable .,

Comment: can I use the map inside the pipe?

Comment: You can return the observer with map and even then the incorrect value continues, there are 9 items I delete 1. in my postman it gets 8 but in my getList it returns me 9

Comment: Just FYI ... since Angular v4.3 we no longer need to use `map` on the response.