# Error in calling json data

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-pipe

I am trying to call the data present in (data/app.json) file.

Below is component(customer.component.ts)file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'; 


@Component({
   selector: 'ylb-customer',
   templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
})
export class CustomerComponent  {

   spaceScreens: Array<any>;

   constructor(private http:Http){
         this.http.get('./data.json')
        .map(response => response.json().screenshots)
        .subscribe(res => this.spaceScreens = res);
      }


 }
```

This error I got

> error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type
>   'Observable'.

For the error i tried this solution too

```
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

and

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Which were marked as correct in this post([Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208801/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse))

Still no result.

this is (customer.component.html)file

```
         <div>
          <mat-card class="example-card">
            <mat-card-header>
              <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image" *ngFor="let spaceScreen of spaceScreens; let i = index">
                    <img src="{{ spaceScreen.img }}">
              </div>
              <mat-card-title><p>{{ spaceScreen.description }}</p></mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
          </mat-card>
          </div>
```

This is (app.json) present in inside folder called data

```
     {   
       "screenshots":[ 
         {
            "img":"assets/img/json_1.jpg",
            "description":"USA"
        },

        {
            "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
            "description":"UK"
        },

        {
            "img":"assets/img/json_3.jpg",
            "description":"INDIA"
        }

    ]        
  }
```

Now getting this error

```
    ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property ‘map’ does not exist on type Observable. The problem was related to the fact that you need to add **[`pipe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)** around all operators.

Change this,

```
this.http.get('./data.json').map(data => {})
```

to this

```
this.http.get('./data.json').pipe(map(data => {}))
```

And

Import map like this,

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

It will solve your issues.

Comment: use safe navigation operator   <mat-card-title><p>{{ spaceScreen?.description }}</p></mat-card-title>

Comment: What about image,I mean this <img src="{{ spaceScreen.img }}">.

Comment: you have to do the same

Comment: Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…>Cannot GET /data/app.json</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}

Comment: you need to put the jso n in you assets folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177326/discussion-between-shankar-guru-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: But text is not loading ,This tag <mat-card-title><p>{{ spaceScreen?.description }}</p></mat-card-title> and images are placing one above the other

Answer (score 1):

Starting from ***RxJS 5.5*** you need to use [**pipeable operators**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) and pass `map` operator into the `pipe` function.

Import `map` operator from the

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
```

and use like

```
this.http.get('./data.json').pipe(
        map(response => response.json().screenshots)
    ).subscribe(res => this.spaceScreens = res);
```

Comment: Hi @Shankarguru if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Ya i know,But i have to wait 5 min to give correct tick mark.Surely i will give after 5 min.

Comment: Maybe you have used `.description` in another place also except view?

Comment: I haven't used anywhere the image is coming ,But no the text