# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'TwitterserviceService'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning to create very simple and basic angular applications. I've decided to show my tweets from my twitter timeline. I followed some youtube tutorials and some blogs. Specially this- [Connect to the Twitter API in an Angular 6 App](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/connect-to-the-twitter-api-in-an-angular-6-app--cms-32315). I was able to create a basic working angular-twiiter app (a made up name). I'll show you my code:

**server.js**
(nothing wrong with this code)

```
const express = require('express');
const Twitter = require('twit');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running'));

const api_client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: 'MY_KEY',
    consumer_secret: 'MY_SECRET_KEY',
    access_token: 'MY_TOKEN',
    access_token_secret: 'MY_SECRET_TOKEN'
})

app.get('/home_timeline', (req, res) => {
    const params = { tweet_mode: 'extended', count: 10 };

    api_client
      .get('statuses/home_timeline', params)
      .then(timeline => {
        res.send(timeline);
      })
      .catch(error => {
      res.send(error);
    });
});
```

Then I created **twitterservice.service.ts**
(error in this code)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TwitterserviceService {

  api_url = 'https:/localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTimeline() {
    return this.http
      .get<any[]>(this.api_url+'/home_timeline')
      .pipe(this.map(data => data));  //ERROR: Property 'map' does not exist ...
  }
}
```

For `map` I'm getting:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'TwitterserviceService'.

However, My **server.js** is working absolutely fine. I've tested it on `Postman` and I'm getting the desired JSON output. I tried finding help on the internet, read some articles and questions like: [Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208801/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse). But still I'm not able to solve this. Please correct me.

Comment: Why did you think it *would*? What are you expecting this.map to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `this.map` with `map`. Using `this` keyword implies `map` is a member variable of 'TwitterserviceService' service.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake I did. I'm accepting this answer. And I'm so sorry I bothered you for this. :-(

Comment: And also I missed adding `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`. I added it later. This was also the issue.

Comment: Well, the import statement is included in the original question however. Its all good as long as you got it working.