# How to get specific fields of Observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, openweathermap

I'm currently working with the OpenWeatherMap API (https://openweathermap.org/current) and I'm trying to get `main.temp`, `main.feels_like`, `main.temp_min` and `main.temp_max` fields of the Observable which I get from an HTTP request.

It's possible for me to get all the data, but I only need these fields. How do I get these fields and put them in my own variables?

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {WeatherServiceService} from "./Services/weather-service.service";
import {LocationData} from "./models/location-data";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

declare const L: any
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

data!:LocationData
location!:string
locationData = new LocationData();

constructor(public weatherService:WeatherServiceService, public http: HttpClient) {
}

ngOnInit() {
if (!navigator.geolocation){
  console.log("location is not supported")
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  const coords = position.coords
  const latLong = [coords.latitude, coords.longitude]
  console.log(
    'lat: ${position.coords.latitude}, lon: ${position.coords.longitude}'
  );
  let mymap = L.map('map').setView(latLong, 13);

  L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}? access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoia29lbnRlcmhlZWdkZSIsImEiOiJja3NpejZibWsxcGFhMzBvZjRlOXhkcWZoIn0.Bs552hPcijlBy1b2kDqfvw', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
  }).addTo(mymap);

  let marker = L.marker(latLong).addTo(mymap);
});
this.watchPosition();
}

watchPosition(){
let desLat = 0;
let desLon = 0;
let id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
  console.log(
    'lat: ${position.coords.latitude}, lon: ${position.coords.longitude}'
  );
  if (position.coords.latitude === desLat && position.coords.longitude === desLon){
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
  }
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
}, {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
})
}

getCoordinates(){

this.weatherService.getData().subscribe((data: LocationData) => this.locationData = {
  temp_min: data.temp_min,
  temp_max: data.temp_max,
  temp: data.temp,
  feels_like: data.feels_like
})

// this.weatherService.getData().subscribe(data => this.locationData = data)

// this.weatherService.getData().subscribe(res =>{
//   console.log(res)
// })



}

}
```

Interface:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {LocationData} from "../models/location-data";

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherServiceService {

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

}

getData() : Observable<LocationData>{
return this.http.get<LocationData>('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Enschede&appid=2a47a80c223baab80003883c31f35729')

}
}
```

Model:

```
export class LocationData {
temp!:number
feels_like!:number
temp_min!:number
temp_max!:number

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is blocking you or doesn't work? At 1st look you already have the whole code..

Comment: He Koen from Enske (my town). You can map it directly in your service. Something like return this.http.get<LocationData>('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Enschede&appid=2a47a80c223baab80003883c31f35729').pipe(map( (data: any) => { return   {
  temp_min: data.temp_min,
  temp_max: data.temp_max,
  temp: data.temp,
  feels_like: data.feels_like
} ))

Comment: (Maybe missing some brackets there, I’m on mobile)

Comment: ..mm.. SO is truncating my comment. Next attempt: return this.http.get<LocationData>('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Enschede').pipe( map( (data: any) => { return {temp_min: data.temp_min, temp_max: data.temp_max, temp: data.temp, feels_like: data.feels_like} } ) )

Comment: @GaëlJ If I print those values, they are all 'undefined' instead of the values it gives if I enter the link in the browser.

Comment: @MikeOne haha that's coincidental! If I add this code in my service, what do I put in my component typescript file? I would like to print out the values as well.

Comment: @KoenterHeegde It is! I see maury844  gave a fine answer. (PS: If you're ever stuck, feel free to ping me on Twitter @Dutch_Guy)

Comment: @MikeOne the code of maury844 isn't completely working yet! Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have almost everything you need already, on your service you can `map` the response to get only the values you want, like this:

This is the structure of the json response:

[image: json structure]

```js
getData() : Observable<LocationData>{
  const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Enschede&appid=2a47a80c223baab80003883c31f35729';
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((response: any) => ({
    temp: response.main.temp,     
    temp_min: response.main.temp_min, 
    temp_max: response.main.temp_max,
    feels_like: response.main.feels_like
  })))
}
```

and then you can just subscribe in your component

```js
getCoordinates() {

  this.weatherService.getData().subscribe((data: LocationData) => {
    this.locationData = data;
  });

  // this.weatherService.getData().subscribe(res =>{
  //   console.log(res)
  // })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using a newer version of RxJS so I have to use pipe(), otherwise the map() function doesn't work. I solved it like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208801/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse). This however gives me the error: 'Property 'main' does not exist on type 'Object'. How can I solve this?

Comment: ah right. return this.http.get(url)..pipe(map( (response: any) => ({
    temp: response.main.temp,     
    temp_min: response.main.temp_min, 
    temp_max: response.main.temp_max,
    feels_like: response.main.feels_like
  })))

..should do it..

Comment: @MikeOne I get the same error again: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable

Comment: Sorry - I missed the missing pipe - so that needs to be in (wrap it in a .pipe) - the trick for your Typescript error is to type the .get response as any. So (response: any) =>

Comment: @MikeOne and maury844 Yes this works! Thank you so much, you are my heroes ;)

Comment: Excellent! Enjoy coding - Angular is fantastic!