# How do I use observable and observer in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I come from a synchronous programming background and I am having a hard time understanding observables.

Here is an extract of my service/provider (Ionic 2 project)

```
return this.http.get(`${this.serverApi}`)
  .map(res => <Response[]>res.json());
```

and I will subscribe to that from the `LoginPage`. I have several questions regarding this.

1. Does the above code return an observable/ observer even if I didn't declare it as such?
2. The response is JSON. How do I do some checking/processing of the JSON and perform some action like if

   ```
   res.auth_token==true
   ```

   then do

   ```
    localStorage.setItem(res.auth_token)
   ```

   I believe it should be done in the provider class. Just a typical hint/example will be awesome.
3. Does the request actually happen when it hits the subscribe method?
4. [Creating and returning Observable from Angular 2 Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675155/creating-and-returning-observable-from-angular-2-service) mentions Subject and ReplaySubject. Should I use them instead?

Comment: 1. It returns the result of `Observable.map`, which is itself an observable. 2. Add another `.map` or do it in the current one. 3. The response is made when you `.subscribe`, yes, not just when you return the observable. 4. I don't see a need to do that in your current code, but... maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The code will return an `Observable`
2. You can change the callback body to a block and add as much code as you want

```
return this.http.get(`${this.serverApi}`)
  .map(res => {
     let x = <Response[]>res.json();
     // do something with x
     res.auth_token == true;
     return res; // with a block body an explicit`return` is required
  });
```

3. Yes, calling `.subscribe()` will execute the `http.get()` and then all subsequent operators when the response arrives. Without `.subscribe()` nothing will happen.

Note: Some Angular APIs expect an `Observable`, in this case you must not call `subscribe()` because `subscribe()` returns a `Subscription`, not an `Observable`.

4. it depends what you try to accomplish. If you use `http.get()`, you already get an observable and there is no need for `Subject`, `ReplaySubject`, or any of the other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense. Regarding ReplaySubject, when should I use it?  My app makes http get, post,put and delete requests btw.

Comment: `ReplaySubject` is useful if subscribers that subscribe later should also receive all previously emitted events. I don't know of a good use case just now, but I'm sure there are many.